How can I find my drafts?
I was editing my question in [SU], then accidentally reused the browser tab for a Google search. How can I find back my draft and continue editing?
I looked at Questions under my profile, and all [Teams] questions, both sorted on 'newest', but it was not there.
I also went to the question list under my profile, sorted on Views
Please note that I could not post my question, there was an erroneous 'Body missing' error when editing. That made that the last two searches  useless, I only 'have' a draft hiding somewhere in the crevices of [SU].

I don't think edits have drafts, but can you re-open the tab (Ctrl+Shift+T, usually) and then use the back button repeatedly?

@wizzwizz4 tried the back button without success

@wizzwizz4 is correct, as we were told here: "Drafts are not supported on edits". And there is already a feature request for that.
